# Is Emacs SE still the best place to ask questions related to Emacs/elisp?

Tags: discussion

I want to emphasize that my intention is not to criticize in any way. I am deeply grateful to the Emacs SE community for all the help I have received over the years. However, lately, I have the impression that there is much less activity on this forum and that even some "veteran" users have reduced their involvement. (Is it just my impression, or are there statistics about this?) Nevertheless, my real question is whether there are other places, perhaps with more activity, where I can seek help. Maybe you could advise me on the order/priority to use these other resources for posting my issues.

Answer (score 2):

I think your impression is correct, or at least it matches mine: there's less activity here than there had been previously.

I suspect this is part of the development of the site. Early on a lot of common, general questions were asked and answered. As we established that core set of Q&As, there's a growing proportion of problems that users can solve with an existing answer, so they don't ask a new question.

Along with that, it seems that the questions that are getting asked nowadays tend to be narrower in scope. Still on-topic, but maybe something to do with a particular mode, or special context. By their nature, these questions get less attention and fewer responses, since there's a smaller subset of people with the knowledge to address them. But they're definitely still on topic here.

Even with the reduced traffic, I think this is still the best place to get specific questions answered. It's not a good place for broader or less structured discussions. Reddit was (and maybe still is? I don't use it myself anymore) better for that.

If you prefer mailing lists, [help-gnu-emacs](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/) is still active, and has been around since at least 2000 (that's as far as the public archive goes, but I suspect the list is older). It's frequented by several/many Emacs developers, and prior to emacs.SE it was (for me) the best source for community help. It may still be, but I haven't been paying attention to it for a while.

There are a few people who are active at all these locations, and a many who live at one or the other. It is good etiquette to ask a question at one location at a time. That is, wait a few days or more after asking a question here before asking at one of the other locations (and only if you don't get a good answer of course!), so as not to annoy the people that do frequent multiple sites.

Comment: Thanks. I believe that the advent of tools like ChatGPT is also contributing to the declining interest in these forums. Personally, before asking on the forum, I try to use these tools myself.